# IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML to collect data from a site

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have made several attempts to collect the data within this table:

[image]

The simple ways of the two functions I've commented on, I've tried, but not succeeded.

**I would like to if anyone knows any other way to collect this data in Google Sheets.**

Site Link:
https://www.onlinebettingacademy.com/stats/team/brazil/operrio-pr/13217#tab=t_squad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the table you want to scrape is under JavaScript control, therefore, it can't be scraped.

all you can get from that site into Google Sheets is:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://www.onlinebettingacademy.com/stats/team/brazil/operrio-pr/13217#tab=t_squad&team_id=13217"); 10000; 10)
```

Comment: I had imagined it, but decided to ask to be completely sure about it. Thank's mate!

Answer (score 0):

Because the page you are trying to scape is rendered using Javascript — i.e. the content you are looking to scrape is not in the markup, you will not be able to use a tool like Google Sheets.

However... you can easily scrape this by using a "headless browser". You pretty much will use a browser (without a UI) that will render your URL with the Javascript, and then once the page is loaded, you query the data using XPATH, etc.

Check out [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) for an example of a JS framework that you can use for this task.