# ImportXML returns Imported Content is Empty

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import two values from [this](https://classic.warcraftlogs.com/character/eu/firemaw/umog) website where it says

> Best Perf. Avg 96.2
>
> and
>
> Median Perf. Avg: 83.4

I tried this formula for Best Perf. Avg:

```
=importxml("https://classic.warcraftlogs.com/character/eu/firemaw/umog", "//*[@id'top-box']/div[2]/div/b)"
```

but it returned `"Imported Content is Empty"` error. The same happens for Median Perf.Avg.

[Also found this in the networks section, it might help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PezOY.png)

What do I write in the `importxml` formulas to get the two values I'm looking for, this is beyond my capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

Original:

```
"//*[@id="top-box"]/div[2]/div/b)"
```

Correct:

```
"//*[@id='top-box']/div[2]/div/b"
```

Convert `"` to `'` and this `)` after `/b` doesn't exist.

**But even adjusting the errors will not work.**

Your case is the same as mine on another page, there is no way to import this data by `IMPORT FUNCTION` because the data if you want to scrape is under JavaScript control, therefore, it can't be scraped.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58945187/11462274

Comment: so no way around it?

Comment: @omakzulu unfortunately not.