# ImportXML to Google Sheets from Live site values. Error

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to import this live value into google sheets using importxml and while I have been successful with other sites this one is giving me some issues.

Currently I am using.

=IMPORTXML("https://dex.guru/token/0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c-bsc","//div[@class='token-value']")

Which returns "error: Imported content is empty".

Any assistance is appreciated especially if it helps me better understand what I am doing wrong. Meanwhile I will keep plucking away at it :D

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the reason why the [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342) function returns `Imported content is empty` is because the data from the [URL](https://dex.guru/token/0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c-bsc) is dynamically being controlled by JavaScript, according to the answer from [IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML to collect data from a site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58945008/importhtml-or-importxml-to-collect-data-from-a-site/58945187#58945187) post. Thus, the function cannot scrape data from that URL.

I've also tested disabling the Javascript on my browser when accessing the  https://dex.guru/token/0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c-bsc and I have confirmed that the data is indeed being controlled by it as the browser showed the message `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app`.

Alternatively, you can still scrape data from dex.guru URL if they have an available API to use. However, upon checking their [website](https://docs.dex.guru/api), the API option is not yet available.

Comment: That is unfortunate, I appreciate your time looking at it and I am sure you saved me a lot of time trying to get it to work.